# Method to fetch SQL Server stored procedure input parameter

Tags: python, sql-server

Is there any way using python to fetch SQL Server stored procedure input parameter names and the number of parameter?

The application is a python GUI, users are allowed to select which stored procedure they want to call. When a particular stored procedure is selected, associate GUI view will change according to what input parameter this stored procedure has.

Comment: do you want to call SQL procedure from python? looking for python code?

Comment: The application is a python GUI, users are allowed to select which Store Procedure they want to call. When a particular SP is selected, associate GUI view will change according to what input parameter this sp has.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query from `sys.parameters`

```
select  *
from    sys.parameters
where   object_id   = object_id ('stored procedure name')
```